# Java genric maximum value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want to implement a function which get the maximum of an array, e.g. double [] {1,2,3}
This array contains the elements which could be compared.
Here is my implementation:

```
   static <T extends Comparable> T Max( T [] arr ){
        T current = arr[0];
        for ( int i=1;i< arr.length;i++){
            if ( arr[i] > current )
                current = arr[i];
        }
        return current;
    }
```

But compiler says bad operand types for binary operator '>'  in

> if ( arr[i] > current )

How can I fix it?

Comment: If `T` extends from `Comparable` wouldn't you use `arr[i].compareTo(current) > 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `T` extends `Comparable`, you should be using the `compareTo` method instead, for example...

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> T Max(T[] arr) {
    T current = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].compareTo(current) > 0) {
            current = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

From the [JavaDocs for `Comparable#compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))...

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
>   The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an
>   exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies
>   x.compareTo(z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that x.compareTo(y)==0 implies that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all
>   z.
>
> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class
>   that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition
>   should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note:
>   this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with
>   equals."
>
> In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to
>   return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression
>   is negative, zero or positive.

Comment: To be fully correct the type parameter should be `<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

Comment: @Spectre Okay, I'll run with that...should really stop copying and pasting original code :P

Answer (score 3):

`>` operator is used for primitives and not on objects. Hence the compiler complains when you do this:

```
if ( arr[i] > current )
```

For objects comparison you should better use `compareTo`. To do that your `T` should be `Comparable`

Answer (score 1):

Also, `Comparator<T>` also requires a type parameter, which is usually written as `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` to actually catch all valid run time types.

```
   public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T highest(T[] array) {
      if (array.length == 0)
         return null;
      T highest = array[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
         if( array[i] == null ) continue;
         if( highest == null || !(highest.compareTo( array[i] ) > 0 ))
            highest = array[i];
      }
      return highest;
   }
```

Invoke as:

```
  System.out.println( highest( new Double[]{1.1,5.2,3.3} ));
```

Lightly tested, caveat emptor.